# message : "Cast to Number failed for value \"NaN\" (type number) at path \"rating\" for model \"Product\""

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mern

ProductModel.js

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    name: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    brand: { type: String, required: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true },
    description: { type: String, required: true },
    price: { type: Number, required: true },
    countInStock: { type: Number, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, required: true },
    numReviews: { type: Number, required: true },
  },
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);

export default Product;
```

so basically i am getting this error i don't know why i am getting this error i checked product model

and i am getting this in payload data
page: null
query: null
category: null
price: null
rating: null
order: null

here is code to fetchData code

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(
          `/api/products/search?page=${page}&query=${query}&category=${category}&price=${price}&rating=${rating}&order=${order}`
        );
        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: data });
      } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
          type: 'FETCH_REQUEST',
          payload: getError(error),
        });
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [category, error, order, page, price, query, rating]);
```

Comment: Check the value of `rating`. Provide the debugging details

Comment: I have checked the rating. and it's number only like 4, 5 and actually i am not getting any errors in terminal but this error showed in  the network